# excluding canadian postal codes during shiping calculation

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm currently designing a website on shopify, and now I have to create rules for shipping using parcelify.
We've manage to get our account to use the legacy version, which allows us to use regex to put restriction on where we can and can't ship. The only thing is  I don't know anything about Regex, so I listened to a couple of tutorials online, and I've come up with a few options, but none of them do what I want to do:
allow shipping anywhere except for postal codes starting with:

- g0c
- g0e
- g0g
- g0j
- g0t
- g0w
- g4r
- g4t
- g4w
- g5j
- g5l
- g8p
- j0m

So I've come up with this, I know it can probably be much simpler, but I'm just trying to get this rule to work, maybe I'm totally off and that's why I'm reaching out for help here.

```
/(^(?!g0C|G0E|G0G|G0J|g0t|g0w|g4r|g4t|g4w|g4w|g4x|g5j|g5l|g8p|j0m)) ?([a-zA-Z0-9]*.{3}$)/gim
```

From what I understand, if I use a negative lookahead that would be the key to exclude the every postal codes with the FSA (first three characters of a postal code) mentioned above.

When I try to put it in regex101, everything seems fine (unless I just don't get how to read the results), but when it comes to putting it into the shopify app (parcelify), acceptable postal codes are not able to place an order because I'm getting blocked at the shipping step...

Every Canadian postal code is built of 6 character if you don't count the space in the middle

Comment: What is an acceptable postal code that gets blocked?

Comment: H1T 1C7 is not accepted, but should be. I'm also try to find a rule that would allow syntax errror, like case insensitive and with or without space in the middle.
Ideally, following this reflexion h1t 1c7, H1T1C7 or h1t1c7 would work.

Comment: it does not match `H1T 1C7` as there should be 3 times any char at the end of the string. Now that will match `1C7`, but the space before it can not be matched by the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. Should there always be 6 char or 7 with a single space after the 3rd char? A pattern like this would match those for example `^(?! ?(?:g0C|G0E|G0G|G0J|g0t|g0w|g4r|g4t|g4w|g4w|g4x|g5j|g5l|g8p|j0m)) ?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$` https://regex101.com/r/a3Phtc/1

Comment: Every Canadian postal code is built of 6 character if you don't count the space in the middle, so in this case 6 or 7 char total would be fine. so following that logic i would simply need to add \s to [a-zA-Z0-9]*?

Comment: then you could do it like this `^(?! ?(?:g0C|G0E|G0G|G0J|g0t|g0w|g4r|g4t|g4w|g4w|g4x|g5j|g5l|g8p|j0m)) ?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9] *){6}$` https://regex101.com/r/NmLkLq/1

Answer (score 0):

If the string can also begin with a space, you can add that to the negative lookahead to rule out that as well.

The `/i` makes the pattern case insensitive.

Also allowing spaces at the end:

```
^(?! ?(?:g0C|G0E|G0G|G0J|g0t|g0w|g4r|g4t|g4w|g4x|g5j|g5l|g8p|j0m)) ?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9] *){6}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `?(?:g0C|G0E|G0G|G0J|g0t|g0w|g4r|g4t|g4w|g4w|g4x|g5j|g5l|g8p|j0m))` Match a space followed by any of the alternatives
- `?` Match an optional space (Or  `*` for multiple spaces)
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9] *){6}` Repeat 6 times matching a char from the character class followed by optional spaces
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lsmxu5/1)

A bit shortened version using character classes and accepting no spaces at the end:

```
^(?! ?(?:g0[Cw]|G0[EGJ]|g0t|g4[rtwx]|g5[jl]|g8p|j0m)) ?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9] *){5}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bzgnne/1)